# Visual Studio can't see Angular project added after creating API project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-webapi

I made a web API project with C#. After that, (when I implemented all the API logic I wanted) I proceeded to add an new Angular app to the existing API project. I did that trough PowerShell with the help of "npm" and "ng".

After successfully creating the Angular app I can't see it in the solution explorer. (The angular app is in the correct directory it just isn't getting recognized from Visual Studio for some reason.)

What am I doing wrong? I tried reloading the files and restarting my PC and everything related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
<!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
<Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
<None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
<None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I added this. I removed the 4th line because again nothing showed up. My VS crashed and I guess reloaded the project and then everything showed up, but the thing I added is in the .csproj file after the crash. Right now I have another problem: when I run `ng build` it gives me the following error:   `The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot to switch to Angular's app directory. I was running the command in the source folder.